# How to change path color of svg file?

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible to change the svg `path` color (not background!) if the svg is loaded from local file.

```css
.status-icon1 {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  mask: url(https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-svgs/blob/main/sprite_icons/status_success.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  -webkit-mask: url(https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-svgs/blob/main/sprite_icons/status_success.svg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

.status-icon2 {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: url(https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-svgs/blob/main/sprite_icons/status_success.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="status-icon1"></div>
  <div class="status-icon2"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Sidenote: I lateron want to reference the svg files locally, not from the web.

Comment: The output is blank in my case. What should be visible there?

Comment: if the file is local, edit it and set whatever colour you want in that file.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#the-problem-with-both-img-and-background-image

Comment: It could be that, GitLab blocks such requests, because it is not a host.

Comment: Yes but the url include is not the problem, as written I have to file locally. The problem is that I cannot set the path color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to implement SVG's into your HTML code and modify it with CSS is another. SVG files contain attributes like `stroke` or `fill`. You can try by referencing these attributes with CSS to change its styling. Also a were frequent method is to put as values into these attributes `currentColor`. So the color is corresponding to its CSS color parameter. Just by changing the wrappers style to `color: green` you will be able to change the `currentColor` inside your SVG.

```css
.status {
  fill: #ff11ac;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  color: green;
  
  img {
    fill: #ff11ac;
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Change fill paremter with CSS</h2>
<div class="status">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 14 14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M0 7a7 7 0 1 1 14 0A7 7 0 0 1 0 7z"/><path d="M13 7A6 6 0 1 0 1 7a6 6 0 0 0 12 0z" fill="#FFF" style="fill: var(--svg-status-bg, #fff);"/><path d="M6.278 7.697L5.045 6.464a.296.296 0 0 0-.42-.002l-.613.614a.298.298 0 0 0 .002.42l1.91 1.909a.5.5 0 0 0 .703.005l.265-.265L9.997 6.04a.291.291 0 0 0-.009-.408l-.614-.614a.29.29 0 0 0-.408-.009L6.278 7.697z"/></g></svg>
</div>

<h2>Change currentColor with CSS</h2>
<div class="status">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 14 14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill-rule="evenodd" fill="currentColor"><path d="M0 7a7 7 0 1 1 14 0A7 7 0 0 1 0 7z"/><path d="M13 7A6 6 0 1 0 1 7a6 6 0 0 0 12 0z" fill="#FFF" style="fill: var(--svg-status-bg, #fff);"/><path d="M6.278 7.697L5.045 6.464a.296.296 0 0 0-.42-.002l-.613.614a.298.298 0 0 0 .002.42l1.91 1.909a.5.5 0 0 0 .703.005l.265-.265L9.997 6.04a.291.291 0 0 0-.009-.408l-.614-.614a.29.29 0 0 0-.408-.009L6.278 7.697z"/></g></svg>
</div>

<h2>IMG "solution" (won't work)</h2>
<div class="status">
  <img 
    src="https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-svgs/-/raw/main/sprite_icons/status_success.svg"/>
</div>
```

There are also some other issues:

1. You shouldn't reference a file inside a repository directly. This won't be allowed by default. So change `https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-svgs/blob/main/sprite_icons/status_success.svg` to `https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-svgs/-/raw/main/sprite_icons/status_success.svg`.
2. If you are adding an SVG as a mask or background, you won't be able to adjust its styling.
3. Even inserting the file as an `src` attribute inside an `<img/>` tag wont't work very well.
4. Changing the `width` and `height` of the SVG that already holds that information (have a look on the SVG code) isn't really possible; not in an elegant.

## Solution

So, after all I would recommend you to just copy the SVG code (it isn't really long), remove some attributes like `width` and `height`, but leave the `viewBox` and resize its wrapper or the `<svg/>` directly with some CSS rulesets.

Last but not least change the `fill` parameter. That's it.

Comment: Great. Is there any (dis)advantage using fill or currentColor property?

Comment: `currentColor` makes it more flexible. Imagine a scenario where you don't know the content of some HTML tags. It could be some text or whatever. So, you adjust `color` of that wrapper and everything will change its color according to the `color` property. This makes it more general to use.

In contrast using `fill` will only effect SVGs. Nothing else. There will be usecases, where you'd like to change the color of a SVG but not some text, that is in the same place; the same wrapper.

So, it is up to your use case :) Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

If you use your svg as image (which seems to be the case here), you can't affect its content : it's a standalone document.
If you use it inline, you can style it : simply put classes inside your svg, and use them in your css.
In this case, if i understand correctly, you wish to use an svg as a mask in order to show a background color (which would then be a pseudo svg fill color). If it's that, you could use your svg inlined, and style it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution using `mask-mode` and `mask-composite` but it works only on Firefox actually.

The idea is to use `luminance` (since your SVG is black/white) so we mask with the white part then we use exclude with a white background to invert the mask and keep the black part of the SVG.

```css
.status-icon1 {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color: green;
  mask: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj8+CjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB3aWR0aD0iMTQiIGhlaWdodD0iMTQiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxNCAxNCI+CiAgPGcgZmlsbC1ydWxlPSJldmVub2RkIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wIDdhNyA3IDAgMSAxIDE0IDBBNyA3IDAgMCAxIDAgN3oiLz4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0xMyA3QTYgNiAwIDEgMCAxIDdhNiA2IDAgMCAwIDEyIDB6IiBmaWxsPSIjRkZGIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDogdmFyKC0tc3ZnLXN0YXR1cy1iZywgI2ZmZik7Ii8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBkPSJNNi4yNzggNy42OTdMNS4wNDUgNi40NjRhLjI5Ni4yOTYgMCAwIDAtLjQyLS4wMDJsLS42MTMuNjE0YS4yOTguMjk4IDAgMCAwIC4wMDIuNDJsMS45MSAxLjkwOWEuNS41IDAgMCAwIC43MDMuMDA1bC4yNjUtLjI2NUw5Ljk5NyA2LjA0YS4yOTEuMjkxIDAgMCAwLS4wMDktLjQwOGwtLjYxNC0uNjE0YS4yOS4yOSAwIDAgMC0uNDA4LS4wMDlMNi4yNzggNy42OTd6Ii8+CiAgPC9nPgo8L3N2Zz4K) center/contain, 
  linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
  mask-composite: exclude;
  mask-mode: luminance;
}

.status-icon2 {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="status-icon1"></div>
<div class="status-icon2"></div>
```

Comment: So there is no crossbrowser solution?

Comment: @membersound as far as I know, it would be difficult especially if you will dealing with random SVG .. the solution I provided wroks here because your SVG is black/white and is circular. Another case will fail with this solution

Comment: Unfortunately the svg is just an example, I want to apply path color on multiple svgs. Is it possible to change the path color statically eg in the file or in the html include?

Comment: @membersound you need to have the SVG inside your code to do this. As external source, it's impossible